# What are some of the features being implemented on this navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I had a quick question regarding the navbar featured on this website (http://www.cs50.net/). If you click on 'FAQ' or 'Q Evaluations,' you'll see that additional content will pull out without the page reloading. The transition along with the gray overlay makes it look quite aesthetic, and it's something I definitely want to learn. I was wondering what CSS and Javascript features are being implemented here, specifically the feature mentioned above. Any other resources would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

After much research, I decided to use Transit for the CSS Animation, then create a `{ display: none }` div element with the proper contents. And using JS, a click triggers the CSS animation & the `fadeIn()` function to slide the content from the left side. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: You might want to start with [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: That arrow animation makes the menu feel sluggish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll want to read up on [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).